# Get PDO result set including dollar character in php

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo, dollar-sign

I have a postgres table with a column (called id) which contains strings. In most cases the strings include a dollar character like `<sdfjkdsaf$test@com>`.
I'm using PDO statements in a php script to fetch the relevant rows and columns of this table including the above described id-column.

But when I try to use the value from the id-column the PDO result for such an id seems to be empty.

```
Example:
Expected result: "id":"<sdfjkdsaf$test@com>", "body":"This is a test", ...
Real result: "id":"","body":"This is a test", ...
```

I guess the reason is that php interprets the dollar character in the string as the beginning of a variable.
Is there any possibility to manipulate the PDO result so that I can use strings containing $ ?

Comment: Look at your page source. The contents inside `<>` are probably there but not showing in the browser, since they're misinterpreted as faulty html.  It isn't related to the `$`.

Comment: Or it is a question of variable interpolation inside double-quoted strings, looking for a non-existent variable starting with the `$`.

Comment: Have you dumped out the raw result from the query w/o any post processing to ensure it isn't your code interpreting the $ sign?

Comment: @Michael you were totally right. I can see the "missing" id content in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely not the dollar character, but the triangular brackets (`<>`). See the source code on your page to see them.

You can use `htmlentities()` to change it into a HTML compliant version. (`&lt; &gt;`)